# Cashbox count program

Tags: python, python-3.x

I wrote this as an aid to count money that is in a cash box. are there any flaws in the code or any improvements I can make.

```
from decimal import Decimal

def moneyfmt(value, places=2, curr='', sep=',', dp='.',
             pos='', neg='-', trailneg=''):
    """Convert Decimal to a money formatted string.

    places:  required number of places after the decimal point
    curr:    optional currency symbol before the sign (may be blank)
    sep:     optional grouping separator (comma, period, space, or blank)
    dp:      decimal point indicator (comma or period)
             only specify as blank when places is zero
    pos:     optional sign for positive numbers: '+', space or blank
    neg:     optional sign for negative numbers: '-', '(', space or blank
    trailneg:optional trailing minus indicator:  '-', ')', space or blank
https://docs.python.org/3/library/decimal.html#recipes
    """
    q = Decimal(10) ** -places      # 2 places --> '0.01'
    sign, digits, exp = value.quantize(q).as_tuple()
    result = []
    digits = list(map(str, digits))
    build, next = result.append, digits.pop
    if sign:
        build(trailneg)
    for i in range(places):
        build(next() if digits else '0')
    if places:
        build(dp)
    if not digits:
        build('0')
    i = 0
    while digits:
        build(next())
        i += 1
        if i == 3 and digits:
            i = 0
            build(sep)
    build(curr)
    build(neg if sign else pos)
    return ''.join(reversed(result))

money = {'nickels' : Decimal(0), 'dimes' : Decimal(0), 'quarters': Decimal(0), 'ones': Decimal(0), 'twos': Decimal(0), 'fives': Decimal(0), 'tens' : Decimal(0), 'twenties' : Decimal(0), 'fifties': Decimal(0), 'one hundreds' : Decimal(0)}

def display_values():

    d = Decimal(money['nickels'] * Decimal(0.05))
    print(money['nickels'], 'nickles = ', (moneyfmt(d, curr='$')))
    d = Decimal((money['dimes'] * Decimal(0.10)))
    print(money['dimes'], 'dimes = ', (moneyfmt(d, curr='$')))
    d = Decimal((money['quarters'] * Decimal(0.25)))
    print(money['quarters'], 'quarters = ', (moneyfmt(d, curr='$')))
    d = Decimal((money['ones'] * Decimal(1)))
    print(money['ones'], 'ones = ', (moneyfmt(d, curr='$')))
    d = Decimal((money['twos'] * Decimal(2)))
    print(money['twos'], 'two dollar coin(s)= ', (moneyfmt(d, curr='$')))
    d = Decimal((money['fives'] * Decimal(5)))
    print(money['fives'], 'fives(s)= ', (moneyfmt(d, curr='$')))
    d = Decimal((money['tens'] * Decimal(10)))
    print(money['tens'], 'ten(s)= ', (moneyfmt(d, curr='$')))
    d = Decimal((money['twenties'] * Decimal(20)))
    print(money['twenties'], 'twenty dollar bill(s) = ', (moneyfmt(d, curr='$')))
    d = Decimal((money['fifties'] * Decimal(50)))
    print(money['fifties'], 'fifty dollar bill(s) = ', (moneyfmt(d, curr='$')))
    d = Decimal((money['one hundreds'] * Decimal(100)))
    print(money['one hundreds'], 'one hundred dollar bill(s) = ', (moneyfmt(d, curr='$')),'\n')
    cashbox_sum()

def cashbox_sum():
    nickels = money['nickels'] * Decimal(0.05)
    dimes = money['dimes'] * Decimal(0.10)
    quarters = money['quarters'] * Decimal(0.25)
    ones = money['ones'] * Decimal(1.00)
    twos = money['twos'] * Decimal(2.00)
    fives = money['fives'] * Decimal(5.00)
    tens = money['tens'] * Decimal(10.00)
    twenties = money['twenties'] * Decimal(20.00)
    fifties = money['fifties'] * Decimal(50.00)
    one_hundreds = money['one hundreds'] * Decimal(100.00)

    print('Cash box total: ',                                  nickels.quantize(Decimal('0.00')) +          dimes.quantize(Decimal('0.00')) + quarters.quantize(Decimal('0.00')) +       ones.quantize(Decimal('0.00')) + twos.quantize(Decimal('0.00')) +  fives.quantize(Decimal('0.00')) +   tens.quantize(Decimal('0.00')) +        twenties.quantize(Decimal('0.00')) +    fifties.quantize(Decimal('0.00')) +     one_hundreds.quantize(Decimal('0.00')),'\n')

def assign_all_values():
    input_nickles()
    input_dimes()
    input_quarters()
    input_ones()
    input_twos()
    input_fives()
    input_tens()
    input_twenties()
    input_fifties()
    input_one_hundreds()
    while True:
        entry = input("do you need to change a value. enter yes or no. ").lower()
        if entry == "yes":
            change_value()
        if entry == "no":
            input("press enter to exit")
            break
        else:
            print(entry, "is not a valid entry")

def input_nickles():
    while True:
        try:
            entry = int(input('how many nickels are in your cash box? '))
        except ValueError:
            print("\nyou must enter a whole number. e.x. 1, 2, 3... do not enter letters or characters such as $\n")    
        else:
            money['nickels'] = Decimal(entry)
            display_values()
            break

def input_dimes():
    while True:
        try:
            entry = int(input('how many dimes are in your cash box? '))
        except ValueError:
            print("\nyou must enter a whole number. e.x. 1, 2, 3... do not enter letters or characters such as $\n")
        else:
            money['dimes'] = Decimal(entry)
            display_values()
            break

def input_quarters():
    while True:
        try:
            entry = int(input('how many quarters are in your cash box? '))
        except ValueError:
            print("\nyou must enter a whole number. e.x. 1, 2, 3... do not enter letters or characters such as $\n")
        else:
            money['quarters'] = Decimal(entry)
            display_values()
            break

def input_ones():
    while True:
        try:
            entry = int(input('how many ones are in your cash box? '))
        except ValueError:
            print("\nyou must enter a whole number. e.x. 1, 2, 3... do not enter letters or characters such as $\n")
        else:
            money['ones'] = Decimal(entry)
            display_values()
            break

def input_twos():
    while True:
        try:
            entry = int(input('how many two dollar coins are in your cash box? '))
        except ValueError:
            print("\nyou must enter a whole number. e.x. 1, 2, 3... do not enter letters or characters such as $\n")
        else:
            money['twos'] = Decimal(entry)
            display_values()
            break

def input_fives():
    while True:
        try:
            entry = int(input('how many five dollar bills are in your cash box? '))
        except ValueError:
            print("\nyou must enter a whole number. e.x. 1, 2, 3... do not enter letters or characters such as $\n")
        else:
            money['fives'] = Decimal(entry)
            display_values()
            break

def input_tens():
    while True:
        try:
            entry = int(input('how many ten dollar bills are in your cash box? '))
        except ValueError:
            print("\nyou must enter a whole number. e.x. 1, 2, 3... do not enter letters or characters such as $\n")
        else:
            money['tens'] = Decimal(entry)
            display_values()
            break

def input_twenties():
    while True:
        try:
            entry = int(input('how many twenty dollar bills are in your cash box? '))
        except ValueError:
            print("\nyou must enter a whole number. e.x. 1, 2, 3... do not enter letters or characters such as $\n")
        else:
            money['twenties'] = Decimal(entry)
            display_values()
            break

def input_fifties():
    while True:
        try:
            entry = int(input('how many fifty dollar bills are in your cash box? '))
        except ValueError:
            print("\nyou must enter a whole number. e.x. 1, 2, 3... do not enter letters or characters such as $\n")
        else:
            money['fifties'] = Decimal(entry)
            display_values()
            break

def input_one_hundreds():
    while True:
        try:
            entry = int(input('how many one hundred dollar bills are in your cash box? '))
        except ValueError:
            print("\nyou must enter a whole number. e.x. 1, 2, 3... do not enter letters or characters such as $\n")
        else:
            money['one hundreds'] = Decimal(entry)
            display_values()
            break

def change_value():
    while True:
        try:
            entry = int(input('\nwhat value would you like to change? please enter a corrosponding number\n\n1. Nickle\n2. Dime \n3. Quarter \n4. One \n5. Two \n6. Five \n7. Ten \n8. Twenty \n9. Fifty \n10. One Hundred\n'))
        except ValueError:
                print(str('that is not a valid option'))
        else:
            if entry == 1:
                input_nickles()
            if entry == 2:
                input_dimes()
            if entry == 3:
                input_quarters()
            if entry == 4:
                input_ones()
            if entry == 5:
                input_twos()
            if entry == 6:
                input_fives()
            if entry == 7:
                input_tens()
            if entry == 8:
                input_twenties()
            if entry == 9:
                input_fifties()
            if entry == 10:
                input_one_hundreds()
            entry = (input("would you like to change another value. enter yes or no")).lower()
            if entry == 'yes':
                print("yyy")
                pass
            elif entry == 'no':
                input('press enter to exit')
                exit()
            else:
                print(entry, 'is not a valid entry')

assign_all_values()
```

Comment: Welcome to Code Review! Are you aware there's an awful lot of code repetition going on in your program?

Comment: yes, I was feeling like I could have made this less repetitive, but I wasn't exactly sure how.

Comment: Thank You. I am teaching myself how to program, Im often am unsure if something I've done is good or not. Python 3.x. I will change that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think above the repetition, this is the most "urgent" thing to change :

`build, next = result.append, digits.pop`

It is very counter-intuitive. Being explicit with `result.append` is much clearer and easy to understand that using `build`. I searched for a little while for a `build` and `next` function in your code without finding them, only to realize this hack.

In the method `display_values`, there's a lot of repetition that could easily be avoided. It would make a lot of sense to have a dictionary that maps `Nickel` to the value `0.05`. This way, it would be easy to do :

```
def display_values():

    money_values = {'nickels' : 0.05, ...}

    for m, amount in money.items():
        d = Decimal(amount  * Decimal(money_values[m]))
        print(amount, 'nickles = ', (moneyfmt(d, curr='$')))

    cashbox_sum()
```

Doing this would also simplify `cashbox_sum` :

```
def cashbox_sum():

    total = Decimal(0)
    for m, amount in money.items():
        total += (amount * money_values[m]).quantize(Decimal('0.00'))

    print('Cash box total: ', total)
```

*I've never used the `Decimal` class, but maybe you can actually quantize only at the end?*

It is also possible to simplify your inputs :

```
def input_cashbox():

    for m in money.keys():
        while True:
            try:
                entry = int(input('how many ', m, ' are in your cash box? '))
            except ValueError:
                print("\nyou must enter a whole number. e.x. 1, 2, 3... do not enter letters or characters such as $\n")    
            else:
                money[m] = Decimal(entry)
                display_values()
                break
```

This would require an effort to refactor `change_value` but I think you should be able to figure it out with the rest of this review.

I didn't test all of this, but I'm sure it would reduce the code duplication a lot.

Comment: Thank you, I have put that into my code. it has brought it from 249 lines to 122.